# Connect two computer over http without public IP

Tags: java, connection, hole-punching

I'll like to computers/clients to connect directly to each other in the case where one or both of them haven't got a public IP. I guess this could be done with a server as a middle man. The connection established in the end must be direct traffic between the clients. How is this possible, and what is the technic called?

I'll really like to see some code fx in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If port forwarding is not an option, there is a mostly-reliable technique you can use with UDP traffic called [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal).  It requires a middle-man server to act as a rendezvous point, but after the initial set-up all traffic will be endpoint-to-endpoint.

This will not work in all cases; it depends on how the various NAT layers map external endpoints to internal entpoints.

TCP NAT traversal is very difficult to implement and has an extremely low chance of even working.

(I have successfully used UDP NAT traversal to establish an OpenVPN connection between two computers at different universities, both behind several NAT layers!)

Comment: Thanks. OK, that wasn't what I would expect. Is that how Skype handles it's traffic? Can this be done in a language like Java?

Comment: Skype uses NAT traversal, yes.  And I actually implemented a basic NAT traversal client and rendezvous server in Java, so yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: Does Skype use UDP hole punching then?

Comment: @Stig: Yes, it does: http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html

Comment: that is a great description! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will propably have to use [hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching) ([TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) or [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)) if both parties are behind NAT. Something like this:

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
volatile boolean connectionEstablished = false;
volatile boolean reveivedSomething = false;
```

Sender-Thread:

```
while (!connectionEstablished) {
  byte[] buf = new byte[256];
  buf[0]=reveivedSomething?1:0;
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
          otherpcpublicaddr, otherpcsport);
  socket.send(packet);
  Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Receiver-Thread:

```
while (true) {
  byte[] buf = new byte[256];
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  socket.receive(packet);
  reveivedSomething=true;
  if (buf[0]==1) {
    connectionEstablished=true;
    break;
  }
  Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

(you would have to do this on both PCs and to exchange IPs and ports using some reachable server as long as they aren't static)

Comment: Thanks. This is the "UDP hole punching" technic, right? Could I hardcode the IP and port on both clients and make this work without the server?

Comment: @Stig: If this is only for a few cases (or even one), you should maybe consider using a simple port redirection rule on both routers.

Comment: great I will try it out. Is seems simple enough.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of a Java fix, but you could use a dynamic dns service to re-route the traffic into the non-public ip. I think they use a client that keeps track of the public client IP that is assigned by their ISP, and reports it to the service, which then updates their host table. There may also be some configuration needed on each system's routers, in order to forward the public request into the private ip.

There would be several techniques used to perform this, port forwarding, NAT, Dynamic DNS, etc

Comment: That's not what Dynamic DNS does.  Even knowing the private IP address, you cannot route to it because it is private.

Comment: Dynamic DNS provides a fixed hostname with a short TTL which is updated when the dynamic *public* IP of a machine changes.